# Matrices of Trace $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, terminology

The set of all $n$-square matrices with trace $0$ is a subspace of the set of all $n$-square matrices. Is there a standard notation and/or name for this subspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. These matrices are called "traceless" or "tracefree", and the subspace comprised of them is called $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, the special linear Lie algebra. This term is used because the traceless matrices form the Lie algebra associated with the special linear Lie group $SL_n$ consisting of all $n$-by-$n$ matrices with determinant $1$.

Comment: Thanks; I don't know much about Lie algebras, but do you just mean that by consequences of the definitions of Lie group and Lie algebra that it turns out that $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ is a Lie algebra of the lie group $\mathsf{SL}_n$? That's interesting...